# How should you triage bad but clear and answerable questions?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, triage

I just got to the triage review of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27645863/java-code-to-determine-triangle-type-pleeeeeeease):
[image: Question asking us to do their homework, including please with 8 e's and 6 question marks]
This is clearly a terrible question that does not deserve space on the front page, but it is almost clear and answerable (needing only some clarifications that he's looking for integer lengths and whether he wants the sum or the individual lengths to be 10-20), and by the criteria of triage ("can be found, understood and answered") questions can be "Looks OK." even if they are terrible. I downvoted it and clicked Skip because I didn't feel it deserved a "Looks OK," but couldn't justify either of the other categories. How should we triage questions that are clear and answerable but that show no research effort and are not useful?

Comment: I disagree that it is a clear question. I've read it 3 times and I still don't get it. Burn it with fire.

Comment: @Mysticial Make that "seemed clear upon first reading, if you don't think about it too hard". The theoretical question of how to deal with a clear but bad question remains.

Comment: It's not an important question is these "clear but bad" questions are just theoretical.

Comment: It seems pretty clear to me- well within the bounds of "Clear enough not to get closed simply because of lack of clarity".

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes "How do I make a Hello World program in Language X?"

Comment: Unsalvageable, either too broad or unclear. Additionally, I'd strongly suggest downvoting (open in a new tab, sadly not available in triage). Unclear when it could theoretically be a good SO question but the description is lacking (e.g. attempts mentioned but not shown); too broad for cases like "code hello world for me" or more complex tasks. If OP is unable to use the freely available resources to figure out how to do hello world in any language (except malboge and APL), I figure you can't assume they know any of the basics (e.g. what a CLI is), and explaining all that is way to broad.

Comment: @Saposhiente - the cited dup is not a good duplicate. I think you just got punked by the community. Be sure you get a good answer if you need it. Based on your question ("How should we triage questions that are clear and answerable but ...") and the triage queue, its not even possible to answer with "Too broad" or "Unclear what you are asking" because its the wrong damn queue! How's that for Meta service!